# Flask-SQlAlchemy Query not consistent between Production and Development config

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So, I am running a `Flask` web app as the frontend to a small `SQLite` inventory database. I am using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` for all of the database interaction. I have a search feature built in, so that you could (for example) find all pieces of hardware assigned to Person X. Or, find all pieces of hardware from Project ABC that have the status Available. The search feature supports optional criteria.

For security reasons, I can't post executable code here, but this is my search function:

```
for system in db.session.query(System).filter(and_(System.assignee_id.like("%{}%".format(assignee_id)),
                                                           System.serial.like("%{}%".format(serial)),
                                                           System.user_id.like("%{}%".format(user_id)),
                                                           System.project_id.like("%{}%".format(project_id)),
                                                           System.status_id.like("%{}%".format(status_id)))):
        results.append(system)
```

The weird thing is, this works perfectly when I run the app in the Development config. But, in my Production config, if I try to use the 'Assignee' or 'User' criteria (both of which are strings of an email address), I get bad results. It shows me a bunch of systems, some of which have the correct assignee, but most of which don't. The only differences between the Production and Development configs are the file path to the `SQLite` database and the authentication mechanism to sign into the application.

Why would this return different results between the two? It works EXACTLY like it is supposed to in the Dev config.

**UPDATE**

After some additional debugging as suggested by the comments, it looks like the problem is in the actual data of the ProductionConfig.  However, when I browse the .sqlite file in DB Browser, initially everything looks correct. Where is it getting these random assignees?

Comment: Did you try debugging it? If yes what did you find? Is the data in dev and prod databases the same? Test it with dummy data and share the results or if the data between the two is different recreate prod in dev and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried copying the production db to the development setup and seeing if the behavior still occurs? And have you tried printing the `assignee_id` the user in inputting in both the dev and the production environment to ensure that the input is not somehow different in the two?

Comment: I have added a few debug logging statements to both configurations, and the json key:value pairs contain the expected data (such as email address).  The key:value pairs are identical between database configs. I created a copy of the Production database file, and ran the query, and it gave me the incorrect responses. I then repeated the experiment in reverse, and it behaved correctly. So, the conclusion is that the issue is with the actual data in the production database.